# Adding listview column comes to 0

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to add the values in the column `Job` but it keeps coming to 0. Why is this happening?

[image]

**MainWindow.xaml.cs:**

```
int jobSum = 0;
int bidSum = 0;
foreach (dynamic item in PlotListView.Items)
{
    jobSum += Convert.ToInt32(item.Jobs);
    bidSum += Convert.ToInt32(item.Bids);
}
JobBidRatioTextBlock.Text = jobSum.ToString();
```

**MainWindow.xaml:**

```
<ListView x:Name="PlotListView" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="228" Margin="5,37,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="424">
    <ListView.View>
    <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False">
    <GridViewColumn Width="99" Header="Plot" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PlotId}"/>
    <GridViewColumn Width="99" Header="Area" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Area}"/>
    <GridViewColumn Width="99" Header="Jobs" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Jobs}"/>
    <GridViewColumn Width="99" Header="Bids" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Bids}"/>
    </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Details about background code running at: http://pastebin.com/z5kpDcUM

Comment: What is running the code in the code-behind? And why isn't that field bound?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET - have a look at http://pastebin.com/z5kpDcUM

Comment: Unrelated: instead of trying to implement your own relational/object mapping, just use Entity Framework. That said, why are you using dynamic instead of the proper object type? And if your column contains numeric data, why do you map it to a property of type string instead of int?

Comment: I don't see the "summation" code anywhere in your paste bin. I'm guessing that code is running before your items collection is populated, then never again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you constructor for MainWindow just below InitializeComponent() write this:

```
        InitializeComponent();
        DependencyPropertyDescriptor
.FromProperty(ListView.ItemsSourceProperty, typeof(ListView))
.AddValueChanged(PlotListView, PlotListView_ItemsSourceChanged);
```

Then add a funtion to MainWindow Class:

```
        private void PlotListView_ItemsSourceChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ////Write your summation code here
    }
```